# rspec for helper class expects module even though there is no module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I added a helper class to my rails project, Foo, at app/helpers/foo.rb. It looks like  this.

```
class Foo
   #....stuff
end
```

I use it in some models, and everything works fine. However, in spec/helpers/foo_helper_spec.rb, I have

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Foo do
end
```

This causes rspec to crash (not report any failed tests, but actually crash), saying

/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:153:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)

If i remove the describe line and just have the file empty, everything works, but I'd like to add some tests soon.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: you class reads 'classs'. is that a typo?

Comment: And the helpers are modules generally. you will have to define as `module Foo`

Comment: @Vimsha, sorry that classs was a typo. It's correct in my code.

Comment: Change it to a module and your rspec should work fine

Comment: @Vimsha you mean just surround the class definition in a module?

Comment: nvm that seemed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rails follows the paradigm of convention over configuration. one of those conventions is, that you put modules into the helpers folder, because they get included into your controllers and views.

that's why rspec fails when it tries to include your module, which is actually a class.

if you need to have a real class in there, i think you should put it in a different directory to make it obvious, that this is not a usual rails helper!

for example, if you are implementing some kind of decorator for your views, put it in a decorators folder. if you are implementing some kind of adapter for your model, put it in the models folder or some model subfolder.

Comment: i didn't realize helpers was treated differently. Thanks.